# Nodejs pass promise resolve to another module to get value

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Hi I'm trying to get a Promise which has already resolved by executing a function that belongs to another module (another javascript file) to get there the value with .then...

This is my code:

saveUrl.js  file:

```js
const manager = require('./manager');

.then(()=>{
return new Promise((resolve, rej)=>{
    resolve(mainUrl)

      //here if I put .then I have the value that I want BUT I want the value to be passed to the manager file 

      manager.getSavedUrlPromise()
    })
})
```

manager.js file:

```js
const mongoSavedUrl = require('./saveUrl');


module.exports={
    
  getSavedUrlPromise(){
    return mongoSavedUrl
    .then(()=>{
       console.log("inside getSavedUrlPromise")
      console.log(promise)
      process.exit()   
    })
   
    
    
  }
  

}
```

It's telling me that:

```js
mongoSavedUrl.then is not a function
```

Comment: `resolve(mainUrl)` - what is this "resolve" doing there with no promises evident? also, saveUrl.js has no exports nor does anything return anything anywhere in there

Answer (score 0):

Ok now it's done, it was an error of the workflow.

In the saveUrl file, it should be the following:

```js
.then((res) => {
  resolve(mainUrl);
});

// I handle the resolve here and decided to call the module function afterwards
.then((url) => {
   return manager.getSavedUrlPromise(url)
});
```

And in my manager file I don't need to put any .then because the promise is already handled in the saveUrl file because I'll pass the value from there:

```js
module.exports={
    
  getSavedUrlPromise(url){
    
       console.log("inside getSavedUrlPromise")
      console.log(url)
      process.exit()   
    
    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `Promise.resolve()` to get resolved promise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve